# File upload not found on request

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5.6

I am trying to upload a file using Laravel but the request in the controller always returns null.
I think my problem is with the JSON that is sent to controller.

I call my controller like this:

```
$request->file('myimage')->store('upload');
// error Call to a member function store() on null

$request->file('myimage')->isValid();
// error Call to a member function isValid() on null
```

Here is my code:

```
$('#product_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('manageproduct.addproduct') }}",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            method:"POST",
            data:new FormData($(this)[0]),
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'false',
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
```

This is my controller:

```
public function addproduct(Request $request)
{
    return $request->file('myimage'); // return nothing

}
```

This is my view:

```
<form method="post" id="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="modal-body">
                <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-12'>
                            <label>Product Image</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class='col-sm-5'>
                            <img src="{{ asset('images/noimage.png')}}" id='img-upload'/>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-7'>
                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                  Browse… <input type="file" name="myimage" id="myimage">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="action" value="Add" class="btn btn-info" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: `contentType: 'false',` seems incorrect - perhaps change that to `contentType: false` first?

Comment: thanks, that solve half my problem, if i do like this $request->file() // return value, but if i do like this $request->file('myimage') // return nothing